# CSS class on SVG embedded with data URL

Tags: css, svg

In [this JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/quqox/7/edit?html,css,output) I have embedded a SVG in a CSS file via a data URL like so:

```
.myClass {
background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='32' height='8'><path fill='%23FFF' d='…'/></svg>");
}
```

The svg shape has a fill colour. I want to control this colour via a css class. Is that possible?

In the JSBin example you can see my attempt to set `.tail.L` to white via a `.bg` class, but it's not working. `.tail.R` shows how things should look, but here the colour is set within the SVG markup.

Comment: Since the SVG markup exists outside of the DOM, you cant access it with css selectors.  You could completely change the background-image of the .bg class to include a white fill.  Or you could move the svg inline.

Comment: It's not possible unless you use JavaScript.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ thx a lot, I get it now. I'll probably move it inline, although also interested whether I can achieve this effect with a mask. If u wanna post that as an answer I'll accept it.